# Binary created with Pyinstaller fails: "No module named ...", "Failed to execute script ..." when using Pipenv

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pipenv

When creating an executable from a simple Python script, Pyinstaller completes successfully. But when trying to run the executable, it fails with a `ModuleNotFoundError`:

```
Traceback...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'git'
[26228] Failed to execute script xyz
```

I have installed gitpython via Pipenv. Why is it not bundled correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided by @vauhochzett is almost correct, but needs a bit of modification as follows. Instead of using pip within pipenv to install pyinstaller, install pyinstaller using pipenv itself.

This means you will need to install pyinstaller into every pipenv you create, but it will sort out the import paths correctly for every venv you use.

Something goes wonky with the import paths when pyinstaller is installed using pip, but everything works as expected when pipenv is used to install the module within the venv as shown below.

```
$ pipenv install pyinstaller
$ pipenv run pyinstaller script.spec
```

Comment: That's really helpful, I'll accept and note in my reply. Thanks!

Comment: @vauhochzett FYI: There appears to be a bug in the current release (3.5 - July 9, 2019) that causes PyInstaller to improperly load `distutils` and generally fail. The development branch contains a patch for this and can be installed using `pipenv install -e git+https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller.git@develop#egg=PyInstaller`

Comment: Oh! Thanks for that, will do.

Comment: @vauhochzett I've also started a Gist that includes some of my learning about pyinstaller - I find the documentation a bit high-level for beginners. Perhaps you'll find it useful: https://gist.github.com/txoof/ad20106b4feae079e0bf0a3af73bbc56

Answer (score 0):

A possible problem here is using the global Pyinstaller installation. This installation does not know about the pip package downloaded with Pipenv.

I tried again within a Pipenv shell and that worked perfectly:

```
pipenv shell
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller script.py -F
```

Now the module is bundled correctly.

**Edit:** I just learned that my answer is not entirely correct. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59440167/5712053) by Aarion fixes my mistake.